# Making a bot/script to write on Google Classroom

Tags: c#, bots, google-classroom

this is my first question, sorry if it is bad.

Anyway, i started learning the basics of C# lately and it was fun, but i started wondering what i could do with it. During quarantine, my school used google classroom to give us work, but at the beggining of every class, we had to get in the correct classroom and say "good morning" in the last assignment. I was wondering if it was possible to build a bot that would detect what time and day of the week it was, and go in the correct classroom and write "good morning"

I searched the web for this, and the closest i got was a discord bot.

Also, im not gonna use it, im just going to make it to get the experience and learn.

I have part of the program, it can aleardy detect what time and day of the week it is and know what classroom it should enter, but it cant actually get in the classroom and do anything.

So, how would i do it? should i use a library or something similar? and can i stay in C# or should i use something like python (im really new to all of this btw)

And forgive me for my english!

Thank you for your time.

(Also, to know what classroom to get in i used a LOT of if statements, but since this is a program only for me and im not gonna sell it, i think its ok. But if it isnt, please correct me!)

for now it says what classroom to enter. oh and the program is in portuguese.

here goes my code:

```
using System;
```

namespace DetectorDeHora
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
// por enquanto o programa detecta dia e hora, e diz qual classroom mandar bom dia,
//usei o horário atual, mas isso seria mudado com o futuro, ah, e por preguiça,
// eu só fiz as primeiras aulas de cada dia, mas quando tiver paciência eu coloco todas.

```
        string hora = DateTime.Now.ToString("t");

        // antes tinha tentado fazer converter DayOfWeek para string e aí comparar, mas 
        //depois percebi que podia muito bem trabalhar com DayOfWeek, isso facilitou bastante.

        DayOfWeek segunda = DayOfWeek.Monday;
        DayOfWeek terça = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
        DayOfWeek quarta = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
        DayOfWeek quinta = DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        DayOfWeek sexta = DayOfWeek.Friday;
        DayOfWeek sábado = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
        DayOfWeek domingo = DayOfWeek.Sunday;

        DayOfWeek hoje = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;

        Console.WriteLine("Today Is " + hoje + "!");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Aperte ENTER para ver a classroom a entrar.");
        Console.ReadLine();


        // A Lot of IF Statements, Yes, But No One Cares.

        if (hora == "13:20" && hoje == segunda)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bom Dia na classroom de Música");
        }else if (hora == "13:20" && hoje == terça)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bom Dia na classroom de Físico-Química ");
        }else if (hora == "13:20" && hoje == quarta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bom Dia na classroom de Matemática");
        }else if (hora == "13:20" && hoje == quinta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bom Dia na classroom de Português");
        }else if(hora == "13:20" && hoje == sexta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bom Dia na classroom de Matemática");
        }else if (hoje == sábado)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dorme. (Sábado)");
        }else if (hoje == domingo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dorme e chora. (Domingo)");
        }
        else


           if (hora == "14:10" && hoje == segunda)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bom Dia Na Classroom De Música.");
        }else if (hora == "14:10" && hoje == terça)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nada, Continuar em FQ");
        }else if(hora == "14:10" && hoje == quarta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nada, Continuar em MAT");
        }else if(hora == "14:10" && hoje == quinta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nada, Continuar em PORT");
        }else if(hora == "14:10" && hoje == sexta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nada, Continuar em MAT");
        }


            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please share your code. I don't think the not is a good idea! I suggest you find another project ;)

Comment: thanks! i have been kinda away from programming lately but im gonna come back!

Answer (score 0):

Great that you start to learn such an awesome language ;)

As it is mostly a learning project I will not focus on a clean solution, so please be aware that what I describe will be a temporary solution that might break anytime - but I think it's a great (but very hard) challenge for learning some deep stuff ;)

Looking at the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest) from Google classroom there seems to be no public API for sending chat messages or joining classrooms. My best guess would be you need to automate a browser - this should be possible by either using something like [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) for .NET - or playing around with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and Javascript in your browser console - then you can develop a TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey-Script or a native browser-plugin. Directly using the API might be another approach, but this is even more complicated and fragile.

Just be aware that it needs a deep amount of reverse engineering using your browsers development tools (usually opened by pressing F12), you can observe the requests in the "Network"-Tab and inspect elements in the "Elements"-Tab. I think this probably is a bit too much for an absolute beginner, maybe you should look for a project that builds on a publicly documented API. However, if you go this path I'd recommend automating button clicks and textfield inputs found by inspecting the "elements" as it's easier to start with than talking directly to the API.

Such reverse engineered solutions always has the possibility to break at any time as the vendor of the system you are "hacking" does not guarantee the API to not change. I wrote some nice scripts to enhance Steam using this approach and they hold up quite well - but this might be different with google.

So, all in all I would recommend to look for another project for practicing - unless you want a really hard challenge.

Comment: thank you! sorry for bothering, guess im gonna stay with the console stuff i was doing :)

Comment: You're welcome - yeah, it's a good idea to start a bit more easy ;)

Comment: I also read up a bit on google classroom - are you sure you are really chatting inside classroom?
As far as I can see from a first glance there is no chat feature available for google classroom - maybe your teacher is providing a link to an external chat tool that maybe has an publicly available API you could automate?

Comment: no, what happens is that the teacher can make an assignment telling us what to do, and we can make a comment in that assignment

Comment: Ah I see. I also can't find anything about this in the API documentation, it seems like Google does not want students to automate their work, only teachers ;)